# Does MarkLogic Content Processing Framework (CPF) pipeline has to be linear or acyclic?

Tags: marklogic

My understanding is that because each state transition has one current state and one future state (on success), the resulting CPF pipeline(s) would be linear as illustrated in the documentation:

[image]

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/pipelines#id_42403

Is it possible that a state can conditionally transit into one state or another state (branch)? Using the above example, is it possible to transit from State B to State C or Sate F based on some condition? This [answer (by @rjrudin)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546615/3546482) suggested a route by manipulating the domain.

If branch can be achieved, is it possible to transit into a previous state (cyclic)? For example, to conditionally transit from State K to State B or State L. This would enable some iterative processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this simple example CPF action module:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace cpf="http://marklogic.com/cpf" 
  at "/MarkLogic/cpf/cpf.xqy";
declare variable $cpf:document-uri as xs:string external;
declare variable $cpf:transition as node() external;
if (cpf:check-transition($cpf:document-uri,$cpf:transition)) then try {
  let $doc := fn:doc($cpf:document-uri)
  return
      xdmp:node-insert-child(
        $doc/book,
        <last-updated>{fn:current-dateTime()}</last-updated>
      ),
  xdmp:log( "add last-updated ran OK" ),
  cpf:success($cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, ())
} catch ($e) {
  cpf:failure($cpf:document-uri, $cpf:transition, $e, ())
}
else ()
```

*(Copied from the CPF guide: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/quickStart#id_76015)*

It is the invocation of `cpf:success` and `cpf:failure` that dictate what state is applied next. The [`cpf:success`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cpf:success) function however has a 3rd param (here empty sequence) that allows you to provide an override for the target state. Using that parameter you can make the document transition to any state you like.

Be careful though, you could easily create infinite loops (by pointing back to a state you already passed before), or dead-ends halfway (by mistyped state names causing it to not get processed any further) if you are not careful..

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have condition/action pairs in the definition of a particular state transition. CPF really doesn't care whether your pipeline is linear or cyclic: it is just looking at the current state of the document and executing the conditions on it to decide what to do next.

If you want to see an example of a looping pipline, the "PDF Conversion (Image Batching)" pipeline loops (source in Installer/conversion/alternatives/batched-pdf-pipeline.xml). The trick is to loop between two distinct states: certain optimizations may defeat attempts to loop back to the same state.